How do I solve for all integers $(m, n)$ for which $32^m + 1 = n^2$?
Question:
Solve for all integers $(m, n)$ for which $32^m + 1 = n^2$ holds true.
So Far:
I started out with some basic elimination such as $m > 1$, as well as $n > 6$ must be odd. Furthermore, as we have $2^{5m} + 1 = n^2$, $m$ cannot be even because on the contrary, if $m$ were to be even — say $m = 2\mu$ (with $\mu ≥ 1$) —, then:
$$n^2 - 2^{5m} = n^2 - \left(2^{5\mu}\right)^2 = 1$$
which is not possible because the difference of two squares greater than $1$ will always be greater than $1$, so $m$ must be odd.
Then, I considered evaluating the power cycle of $32$ modulo $10$.
$$32 \equiv 2\pmod{10}$$
$$32^2 \equiv 4\pmod{10}$$
$$32^3 \equiv 8\pmod{10}$$
$$32^4 \equiv 6\pmod{10}$$
$$32^5 \equiv 2\pmod{10}$$
but of course, we can strike out moments when $m$ is even, leaving us with $32^m \equiv 2, 8\pmod{10}$, i.e., $32^m + 1 \equiv 3, 9\pmod{10}$.
On the other hand, the possible remainders for $n^2$ modulo $10$ are $n^2 \equiv 1, 9, 5, 9, 1\pmod{10}$. The only match is $m \equiv 3\pmod{10}$ and $n\equiv 3, -3\pmod{10}$.
I have no idea what to do from here...

I don't suppose you want to use Mihailescu's theorem?

Compare with solving $2^m+1=n^2$ in art of problem solving. Or here.

So $2^m+1=n^2$ has as only the solution $(m,n)=(3,\pm 3)$, and hence your equation has no solution. This is easier than to use Pell's equation.

$(n-1)(n+1)=2^{5m}$, so $n-1$ and $n+1$ are both powers of $2$ and have distance $2$, so they must be $2$ and $4$. In other words $n=3$, which means that there's no solution.
An alternative (unnecessary) solution is to notice that $m=2k+1$ (by looking $\mod 3$), which means that you have $x^2-32y^2=1$ where $y=2^{5k}$. This is the Pell equation with $D=32$, which has smallest solution $(17,3)$ and so the other solutions are the $(x_j,y_j)$ such that $x_j+4\sqrt 2 y_j=(x+4\sqrt 2 y)^j$. From this, for example, you can easily see that $y_j$ is always divisible by $3$, so there are no solutions to the original problem.

You know $m$ must be odd. The positive integer solutions of the Pell equation $32 x^2 + 1 = y^2$ are given by the recurrence $[x_{n+1},y_{n+1}] = 34 [x_n, y_n] - [x_{n-1},y_{n-1}]$ with $[x_0, y_0] = [0,1]$ and $[x_1, y_1] = [3,17]$.  It can be seen that all $x_n$ are divisible by $3$. But you want $x$ to be a power of $2$.

This is interesting, but as suggested in Dietrich Burde's question comment, and also mine which I've deleted, it's considerably simpler and more straightforward to just use that we have $2^{5m}=n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$, so both $n-1$ and $n+1$ must be powers of $2$.
